# java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed on sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, sqlexception

I looked at many answers but unfortunately none answers my question and I still can't figure this out why I'm getting `ResultSet closed`.

Here is the `try` code snippet that`s causing the issue:

```
        System.out.println(" System Info! @CHKMD5Files(): Found pre-existing details: "+TOTAL);

        Statement stmMD5 = null;
        Connection connMD5 = null;
        ResultSet rs_MD5 = null;
        String RESULTMD5 = null;

        try {
            connMD5 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + bkpPATH+ hostname + ".db");
            stmMD5 = connMD5.createStatement();
            connMD5.setAutoCommit(false);

            while (ROWID <= TOTAL) {
                rs_MD5 = stmMD5.executeQuery("SELECT md5 FROM details WHERE ROWID = '"+ROWID+"';");
                RESULTMD5 = rs_MD5.getString("MD5");
                skipBuffer.write(RESULTMD5);
                skipBuffer.newLine();
                skipBuffer.flush();
                ROWID++;
                }
            System.out.println(" System Info! @CHKMD5Files(): Done with try");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(" System Error! @CHKMD5Files (2): " + ex);
            System.exit(5);
        } finally {
            if (stmMD5 != null){
                stmMD5.close();
                System.out.println(" System Info! @CHKMD5Files (2): Closing Statement(stmMD5)");
            }
            if (connMD5 != null) {
                connMD5.close();
                System.out.println(" System Info! @CHKMD5Files (2): Closing Connection(connMD5)");
            }
            skipBuffer.close();
        }
    }
```

Looks like the while loop does not even run because if I put print statement in the loop returns nothing.

Comment: At what point are you getting this error?

Comment: Could you add the stack trace of the error?? It would help a lot

Comment: "Looks like the while loop does not even run because if I put print stament in the loop returns nothing." It means ROWID variable is giving you the problem. So put code for it. i.e. query part which stores result in ROWID.

Comment: that actually depends on where she put the print statement: if she puts the print statement as last line inside the while-loop and the error is caused by the first line (or any other) then it would be normal the print doesn't work

Comment: @ManojShukla But I doubt that is the error, else she wouldn't receive that exception I think. I would rather think it has something to do with the `execute` of the statement

Comment: why your `connMD5.setAutoCommit(false);` after `stmMD5 = connMD5.createStatement();`?

Comment: @J.Baoby , No friend, no problem with ` execute ` of the statement. Its seems to be the problem of ` next()  ` method. ` next() ` method points the rows of result returned by query fired to database. Initially pointer points to -1th position i.e. one row before the actual result starts, that is why we need to call ` next() ` method to initialize the pointer to actual resultSet. and if no result is returned ( i.e. if null set is returned ) then again this pointer will point to ` null `. So semantically we should write our code as ` if( rst.next() ) { // then only do this,} else{// do this.. }`.

Comment: Yes I saw it. Have your read my answer? I had added a little advice about `PreparedStatement`s. It should help your program a lot ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use a `ResultSet`, you have to call the [`next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) method first to set the pointer of the `ResultSet` on the first row of the results. As the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) of the method says:

> A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; ...

So if you don't call it, you ain't pointing to no result and the `getString` method (used in `RESULTMD5 = rs_MD5.getString("MD5");`) will generate that exception. So add at least

```
rs_MD5.next()
```

before you extract the results. The `next` method returns a boolean value to indicate if it could get to following row or not. So you might want to add an `if`-statement to check if that value is true before extracting any column-value because if the `next` failed getting to the next row (and returns false) it will set the pointer to no valid row(there are no left) and you'll get the same error if you try to access the results (see the link to javadoc of `next` above).

But unfortunately **even if you would add a call to `next`, you will get the same error in the second iteration** because you can't use the same `Statement`-object to execute different queries.
**Each `Statement`-object can only result in one `ResultSet`**.
 To solve this you should at least replace

> ```
> rs_MD5 = stmMD5.executeQuery("SELECT md5 FROM details WHERE ROWID = '"+ROWID+"';");
> ```

with

```
rs_MD5 = connMD5.createStatement().executeQuery(
        "SELECT md5 FROM details WHERE ROWID = '"+ROWID+"';"
  );
```

But I would suggest you otherwise because creating a new `Statement`-object is quite time consuming (each one has to be compiled before getting executed). As the only thing that changes at each iteration is the `ROWID`  it would be a terrible waste of time to recompile the same thing again at each iteration. So use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead. It allows you to use a statement that gets compiles only once and that you can reuse multiple times by injecting parameters in it (after it compilated).
To use a `PreparedStatement` you should do:

```
Connection conn = ... //Connection to your database
PreparedStatement ps = conn.preparedStatement("SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = ? AND age = ?");

//First search all persons with name "J.Baoby" and age = 5
ps.setString(1, "J.Baoby");
ps.setInt(2, 5);
ResultSet set1 = ps.executeQuery();
// Do something with it 
// ....

//Now I need persons with name "Henry" and age = 25
ps.setString(1, "Henry");
ps.setInt(2, 25);
ResultSet set1 = ps.executeQuery();
// Do something with it
// ...
```

The way to inject those parameters is to use a `setXXX` method with as first argument the index (1-based) of the "?" you want to replace and the second argument is the value. The `XXX` is replaced by the type of the value you want to inject. There are only limited types of parameters you can inject so check the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) first before injecting an object in it.
You can find more info about `PreparedStatement` in the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) 
or on [on this site](http://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface) (with some more examples).

As last I'd like to add that you should close all your (JDBC) ressources (`Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet`, `PreparedStatement`, ...) when you're sure you won't need them anymore. Ressources you don't release are wasted ressources your JVM could have allocated to something else. Not closing your ressources is a bad habit and could result in a performance penalty.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Many Thanks for all your responses and for pointing me in the correct PATH I have managed to fix the issue and it was because the ROWID had no data at the start and that was causing me the issue.

The additional statement checking if it is empty resulved my issue:

```
                while (ROWID <= TOTAL) {
                rs_MD5 = stmMD5.executeQuery("SELECT md5 FROM details WHERE ROWID = '"+ROWID+"';");
                if (!rs_MD5.next() ) {
                    System.out.println(" System Info! @CHKMD5Files(): No data in rowid: "+ROWID);
                    ROWID++;
                } else {
                    RESULTMD5 = rs_MD5.getString("MD5");
                    skipBuffer.write(RESULTMD5);
                    skipBuffer.newLine();
                    skipBuffer.flush();
                    ROWID++;
                    rs_MD5.close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: This gave me  some insight i had not see coming, thanks